# Text Wrap with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap

I have a much longer string of numbers randomly generated. I am displaying it in one div block. As it is much longer single string. It is being written in one single line.

For example:

```
String str="13,7,5,1,10,7,18,11,17,10,9,16,17,9,6,19,6,13,2,18,6,9,8,5,15,4,17,16,12,8,19,16,5,9,6,16,16,5,16,12,0,14,7,11,12,11,12,16,8,3,16,3,1,10,4,14,5,9,4,3,8,3,0,19,5,7,8,7,13,14,4,3,12,6,5,19,17,3,3,19,0,4,14,8,15,17,14,5,9,3,9,19,18,8,10,0,6,1,18,16,3,16,10,9,15,10,4,7,1,7,11,6,11,16,4,11,10,1,0,15,16,19,6,15,18,14,16,16,5,17,9,19,12,7,14,14,11,19,18,10,9,5,11,2,9,0,3,15,14,1,7,14,12,17,1,10,14,5,17,16,19,10,12,6,19,16,5,19,10,9,18,14,11,9,1,18,0,10,0,19,7,17,2,4,14,2,1,3,9,17,11,7,12,4,7,5,17,2,1,6,19,14,5,3,2,6";

<div id='row' style='width:100px;height:500px;'>

</div>
```

I have set the fixed width to div block. I want to display this longer string in multiple rows,rather than displaying in one line.

I tried css `'text-wrap:normal'`. It doesn't work. Actually, this property doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: _"The `text-wrap` property is not supported in any of the major browsers."_

Comment: Well, you *could* use spaces after the commas. Does that conflict with your goals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `word-wrap:break-word;` css style:

```
<div id='row' style='word-wrap:break-word;'>
13,7,5,1,10,7,18,11,17,10,9,16,17,9,6,19,6,13,2,18,6,9,8,5,15,4,17,16,12,8,19,16,5,9,6,16,16,5,16,12,0,14,7,11,12,11,12,16,8,3,16,3,1,10,4,14,5,9,4,3,8,3,0,19,5,7,8,7,13,14,4,3,12,6,5,19,17,3,3,19,0,4,14,8,15,17,14,5,9,3,9,19,18,8,10,0,6,1,18,16,3,16,10,9,15,10,4,7,1,7,11,6,11,16,4,11,10,1,0,15,16,19,6,15,18,14,16,16,5,17,9,19,12,7,14,14,11,19,18,10,9,5,11,2,9,0,3,15,14,1,7,14,12,17,1,10,14,5,17,16,19,10,12,6,19,16,5,19,10,9,18,14,11,9,1,18,0,10,0,19,7,17,2,4,14,2,1,3,9,17,11,7,12,4,7,5,17,2,1,6,19,14,5,3,2,6
</div>​
```

**[LIVE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/njpwQ/)**

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap):

> The word-wrap CSS property is used to to specify whether or not the browser is allowed to break lines within words in order to prevent overflow when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit.

About the `text-wrap` that you tried: I could not find it in `MDN`!, but found this in `w3school`:

> "The **text-wrap** property is not supported in any of the major browsers."

Comment: Please avoid referring to w3schools, it's not a reliable resource http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Emyr. Didn't find it anywhere else(As I wrote in the answer...), don't be nuisance.

Comment: What about the authoritative source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-wrap? Also keep in mind that CSS Text Level 3 is still a working draft, so changes can and will be made and authors shouldn't rely on any behaviour or implementation support.

Answer (score 3):

Write `word-wrap:break-word` in `.row` DIV css. Write like this:

```
#row{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rfc2j/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just use `word-wrap: break-word`

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Rfc2j/

Answer (score 2):

Use `word-wrap:break-word;` property instead of `text-wrap:normal`

Comment: Dude try to get way from spelling mistakes here - brek-word should be break-word.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a space after each comma. Such presentation is normal in human languages, and it improves readability of numeric sequences too (though I wonder what it is generated for—why would it be needed?). You can tune the amount of spacing by setting `word-spacing` to a negative value.

If you do not want any spaces for some reason, generate the `<wbr>` tag after each comma. Frowned by standards-writers (except HTML5) but virtually universally supported by browsers. However, to cover some modern oddities (in IE and Opera), add the following to your stylesheet: `wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }`.

Note that if you use `word-wrap:break-word`, which is supported by many browsers but not all, browsers will feel free to break between digits and before a comma, too, e.g. breaking “42” to “4” at the end of a line and “2” at the start of the next line.